# Odd requests to health_check.js show up in Fiddler

Tags: malware

I had Fiddler running and noticed that there are few calls made to following url:

```
http://www.yimgr.com/health_check.js?ts=1412350007104
```

the content is just this JSON payload

```
{
  "chance": 0.5,
  "blacklist": [
    "stackoverflow.com",
    "html5rocks.com",
    "xda-developers.com",
    "netflix.com",
    "shutterfly.com",
    "techrepublic.com",
    "github.com",
    "android.com",
    "jquery.com",
    "samsung.com",
    "mashable.com",
    "yahoo.com",
    "tenmanga.com",
    "vice.com"
  ]
}
```

The only things running were Chrome, IE, and IntelliJ IDEA, so my first guess it's either spyware or a Chrome extension.
So my question is whether it's part of something malicious and is there a way to check what made this request?

---

**EDIT**

After a bit of digging I found that file name in one of Chrome extensions, namely ruul (on screen caliper). I've installed it a while back but now it's no longer available from Chrome Store

Comment: Who would wanna blacklist stackoverflow and netflix?  Maybe this is your boss telling you to stop goofing off and get back to work? xD

Comment: @RocketHazmat so that people don't ask for help on SO about removing this malware. They just didn't understand that they should block security.se instead. :p

Comment: I Googled `health_check.js` and found this: http://stopmalvertising.com/security/bookmark-sentry-google-allows-ads-in-chrome-apps-and-extensions.html  Maybe it's related?  It has a link to `http://www.imgclck.com/health_check.js`, which seems to be the same file as you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Chrome extension.  What's happening is that some extension is injecting its own ads into webpages.  That way, they can get the revenue instead of the webpage you are visiting.

This JS file seems to be a blacklist of sites where they won't inject ads (or so, I am assuming).

Reference: http://stopmalvertising.com/security/bookmark-sentry-google-allows-ads-in-chrome-apps-and-extensions.html

Comment: My chrome extension ended up being Chromoji I'm pretty sure.  I removed it and haven't seen it since.